# JQuery not having effect on jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a search button, once clicked, it will call editAction.java. I do not want the page to refresh after i clicked the search button (i have a search feature on my jsp page). Even after including the javascript at the bottom of my jsp page, restarted tomcat server, yet it still does not take effect. May i know what am i doing wrongly here?

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-search" type="submit"  name="action" value="search" id ="search">Search</button>
```

**Javascript used**

```
<script>
        $('#search').click(function (e)
        {
             e.preventDefault();
             var val = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: editAction.java,
                type: 'POST',
                data:
                        {
                            $('#search').val();
                        },
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    alert('Successful');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: "yet it still does not take effect" Please clarify.

Comment: Use  "return false;"

Comment: @Tehmina what do u mean? able to show me?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis it still refreshes

Comment: Do you have a form for the button? if so it will submit it on click, you will need to remove the form or add `$('form').submit(function() { return false; });`

Answer (score 0):

make sure jquery is included in your scripts

also when you open your page in the browser open developer tools usually f12 and check for any error displayed

and please post a complete working/error producing code so we can actually help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url is correct.
After you restart your tomcat, you need to clear your browser cache only can work with new version of your Javascript. Try ctrl + shift + del

Answer (score 0):

Try removing type="submit" from button tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this snippet:

<button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-search" value="search" id="search">Search</button>

$('#search').click(function (e) {
    $.post("your url", {
        searchValue: $('#search').val()
    }, function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```